# Failure Writing a Multi-Session Audio/Data CD w/ cdrdao

Tags: burning, audio-cd

I'm trying to create a multi-session CD (CD-Extra), but hitting some errors with `cdrdao`. I'm following [these steps](http://octo.it/cdextra.shtml).

The audio session of the CD finished successfully, but writing the data portion results with:

```
[valid=0] Info fld=0, Current 
SCSI command failed: sense key: 0x05: Illegal Request
Raw sense data: 0x70 0x00 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00 
0x00 0x00 0x21 0x02 0x00 0x00 
ERROR: Write data failed.
ERROR: Writing failed.
```

I tried with the `generic-mmc-raw` driver, and get another error message:

```
ERROR: Cannot set write parameters mode page.
```

Any ideas on what would cause this? Is there another method that can be used to create a mult-session disc?

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything I could think of with `cdrdao`, but I couldn't get past the error.

Then I tired `cdrecord`, and it worked fine.

```
cdrecord data.iso
```

I still was able to make the first session of the disc using `cdrdao`, which was the important part for me.

Comment: Why don't you use cdrecord to write the first session? Cdrecord has more features than cdrdao and is actively maintained while cdrdao is unmaintained since 2008.